# Why can't I fully put Zynq-7000 into low power?

Tags: arm, xilinx, zynq

Why does any of the following register writes cause my program to halt?

- slcr.DDR_CLK_CTRL[DDR_2XCLKACT] = 0
- slcr.DDR_CLK_CTRL[DDR_3XCLKACT] = 0
- slcr.DDR_PLL_CTRL[PLL_BYPASS_FORCE] = 1
- slcr.DDR_PLL_CTRL[PLL_PWRDWN] = 1

I'm new with embedded development and I'm trying to implement some bare bones C code to put the zynq 7000 into sleep mode per [page 674 of the Technical Reference Manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf#page=674)

All of the sleep mode steps execute without issue except for the steps listed, all of which relate to DDR, and all of which halt execution. Leaving the DDR steps out the code functions but I'm not sure I'm reaching the lowest power state.

I'm using the on-board button of my Cora Z7-07S development board as an interrupt source. The handler for the interrupt on button-down executes the power down function and executes the wake function on button-up.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/Micro-Studios/Xilinx-GPIO-Interrupt/blob/master/GPIO_Interrupt.sdk/GPIO_Interrupt/src/helloworld.c) ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPVTVNtJ7R4)) on my Cora Z7-07S to get the interrupt functioning. Does using the AXI GPIOs as an interrupt source create some dependence on DDR? Is there a way to setup the PL to avoid this and still allow a GPIO interrupt?

Comment: By a chance your instructions that turning off DDR are in DDR memory ?

Comment: @user3124812 this could explain it. how would I know if my instructions are in DDR memory? I didn't explicitly put them in DDR, but I realize that doesn't mean they aren't. Is there a method to ensure instructions use alternate memory that's still powered?

Comment: by checking physical address of memory that contains these instructions of course. If I remember correctly Zynq7000 has 1MB of static memory that's used by first stage bootloader (FSBL). That's memory is used at the very beginning to init peripherals and DDR. Place you 'going to sleep' code there, and execute.

Comment: @user3124812 I tried generating a new linker script and pointing everything to ps7_ram_0 instead of the default ps7_ddr_0, then rebuilt, but getting the same behavior. Is there a good tutorial/example that's good for a beginner that demonstrates how to manage and verify code and data memory storage locations?

Comment: @user3124812 I did confirm by stepping through with the debugger that my linker script changes enabled the code to proceed past the DDR steps, to complete the full sleep procedure (it didn't before). The problem is now that it doesn't respond to the GPIO interrupt to wake.